# Issue while adding commons validator dependency in pom.xml of Spring 3.1 project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my project, which is being developed in Spring 3.1,  I am trying to perform both client side and server side validations by making use of Apache Commons Validator. But just by adding the below mentioned  code is causing some xml exception.

added dependency in pom.xml: -

```
                    <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
                         <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId> 
                         <version>0.8</version>
                    </dependency>
```

compile time exception in servlet-context.xml --> Resource Path Location Type Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Users/shift/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd).

I read somewhere that the jars of Spring 3.1 might be colliding with Spring 2.x (which is added in maven repository as [i]spring-modules-validation[/i] brings it with it). After that I added an exclusion as mentioned below: -

```
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
```

After which the exception disappeared but inbuilt classes like InternalResourceViewResolver, DataSourceTransactionManager, etc. are not found by the compiler.

Is there something else which I have missed, or any other way apart from Commons Validator to perform client and server side validations in Spring 3.1 ?